# How to make custom pagination?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, pagination

Which gem am I supposed to use to be able to make pagination with my own fonts and styling?

For example, I want something like this:

[image]

which redirects to `/page/2`

How would I go to get this kind of pagination?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: You can use https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate or https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari and can override default styling easily

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend one from [Kaminari](https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari) or [WillPaginate](https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate). You can style your links very easily.

**As an example**, here is `will_paginate` link styling:

Add html to your pagination links in your `config/locales/en.yml` file

```
en:
  will_paginate:
    previous_label: <span class="my-older-post"><img src="/images/my-older-post.png" /></span>
    next_label: <span class="my-newer-post"><img src="/images/my-newer-post.png" /></span>
```

**Another way** can be overriding [LinkRenderer](https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate/blob/master/lib/will_paginate/view_helpers/link_renderer.rb) of the gem.

Comment: putting markup sounds like a bad idea. if the img url changes for some reason, do you really want to change all your translations?

Answer (score 2):

[Kaminari](https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari) gem gives you pagination [link views](https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari/tree/master/app/views/kaminari), so you can change them in anyway you want.

You can also use [will_paginate](https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate) and override their [`LinkRenderer`](https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate/blob/master/lib/will_paginate/view_helpers/link_renderer.rb).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [kaminari](https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari) gem.

Exmaple usage:

Controller:

```
@users = User.page(7).per(50)
```

View:

```
<%= paginate @users %>
```

You can edit kaminari values in `Rails.root/config/locales/en.yml`

```
en:
  views:
    pagination:
      first: "&laquo; First"
      last: "Last &raquo;"
      previous: "&lsaquo; Prev"
      next: "Next &rsaquo;"
      truncate: "&hellip;"
  helpers:
    page_entries_info:
      one_page:
      display_entries:
        zero: "No %{entry_name} found"
        one: "Displaying <b>1</b> %{entry_name}"
        other: "Displaying <b>all %{count}</b> %{entry_name}"
      more_pages:
        display_entries: "Displaying %{entry_name} <b>%{first}&nbsp;-&nbsp;%{last}</b> of <b>%{total}</b> in total"
```